# DynamoDB: deleting global tables with replicas

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I'm having trouble figuring out how to automate the process of adding and removing tables that have replicas (2019.11.21 table version)

Scenario: I have a table in us-east-1 and update it with a replica in us-west-2. Some time later, I want to delete these tables using an automated script with aws cli.

Since deleting a table does not remove its replicas (why???) I need to delete the replica, and once. that has completed, delete the original table.

I tried

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name some-table --region us-east-1 --cli-input-json \
'{
  "ReplicaUpdates":
  [
    {
      "Delete": {
        "RegionName": "us-west-2"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

But after that I am not sure how to continue. I can't use "wait" because deleting a replica does not change the status of the table. I also can't just "wait" for the replica table to no longer exist because the original table will often still be stuck in the updating phase after the second table is deleted.

What's a sane way to automate removing replicas and deleting tables?

Answer (score 0):

I was also trying to automate the same process, but using the Java SDK instead of the AWS CLI. I got an error like this:

> The resource which you are attempting to change is in use. (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: E07SSSKFG0VBCEKHEV6JQC419RVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, Extended Request ID: null)

I managed to solve this by waiting for the main table to become active.

So here's how to properly delete a DynamoDB global table and all of its replicas:

1. For each region where you have a replica, remove that replica from the global table using the `update-global-table` method as you did.
2. Wait for the master table to become active with `waiter.waitUntilTableExists()`
3. Check if all replica tables have been deleted (as pointed out by Shannon below)
4. Delete the master table in `CURRENT_REGION`

Here's the Java code for that:

```
getReplicaRegions().stream().filter(r -> !r.equals(CURRENT_REGION)).forEach(region -> {
    getClient().updateGlobalTable(b -> b.globalTableName(table).replicaUpdates(ReplicaUpdate.
            builder().delete(d -> d.regionName(region)).build()));
        waitForActive(table, CURRENT_REGION);
    getClient(region).deleteTable(b -> b.tableName(table));
});
waitForActive(table, CURRENT_REGION);
getClient().deleteTable(b -> b.tableName(table));
```

Comment: I don't think step 3 "Delete the actual replica table in that region" is necessary. When you remove the replica, the table in the replica region is deleted automatically. Also, it's not enough to wait until the last table becomes ACTIVE status again, you need to wait until the removed replicas are no longer listed (they will be in DELETING state). Only then will deleting the last table work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I also wasn't 100% sure about that as the docs are a bit unclear.